# DB2 query for fetching clob value

Tags: db2, clob

In DB2 , how do we write a query to fetch value from clob datatype column

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help with your situation, but we ran into a similar situation at my company. For us, we were able to read the values out as a normal string using C#/.NET and the IBM iSeries data provider.  The data we wanted to fetch from the CLOB was just simple text, which allowed this process to work.

Answer (score 0):

For sql/pl, you can select clob data from database same other type, but if you use jdbc I should byte[] for Clob data.

Comment: thanx for the suggestion. This is the first time i am using DB2.. is the. I need to test the query with a standalone class, is the driver for DB2 available as free.